# writting to buffer from serial input

Tags: programming, pointer, buffer

Can some one explain this behaviour please, i have the following code

```
  byte buffer[512];
  byte block;
  byte len;

  Serial.setTimeout(60000L) ;     // wait until 20 seconds for input from serial
  // Ask personal data: Family name
  Serial.println(F("Type text followed by #"));
  len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 500) ; // read from serial
  Serial.print(len);
  for (byte i = len; i < 250; i++) buffer[i] = '#';     // pad with #
  Serial.print(len);
```

This works but if i change the "for" line to any thing higer then 250 it stops working and there is a "buffer out of memory condition)

My question is why can't the for loop say the below as the buffer size is 512?

```
for (byte i = len; i < 512; i++) buffer[i] = '#';
```

Am i right in thinking it has something to do with  (Char *), i did copy this code from the example ardunio code and was jsut trying to incress the lenth of input it accpeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte can only contain values from 0 to 255 (including).

So my guess it works for values until 255.

You should use a different type, e.g. unsigned int or unsigned short.

```
for (unsigned short i = len; i < 250; i++) buffer[i] = '#';     // pad with #
```

Also, I advise to use a constant or define for the buffer size, now you have 3 values (512, 500 and 250 in the loop, I assume they should be based on the same value).

About the char*: Looking at [StreamReadBytesUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StreamReadBytesUntil), it seems that the parameter wants a char* instead of a byte* (which is more or less the same), but it's better to cast to show the parameter is of type char* since that is high likely the exact type (but the official Arduino documentation does not show the parameter types sadly).

Comment: I agree use same constant, it was original but i was playing about when i tried to go over 250. the fact is broke at 254 should have told me this.

Comment: No problem, btw, I opt to close this questions since it's not related to Arduino, but you can continue coding, good luck.

Comment: you could  also explain why (char *) is used in this code, is that there to insure it write to the begining of the buffer. why cant you jsut use "buffer" or is there a particaul advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: I added a note about it.

Comment: for `len` is byte small too

Comment: That make sence, thank you for takeing the time out to help.

Comment: @See Juraj's remark ... btw, unless you know beforehand you might run into memory problems, always use int or unsigned int. Or if you want to do it better, create a specific type for it: `typedef unsigned short buffer_length`

Comment: Brillent all and it addresses some other problems in the code block i was writing the example used "byte" a lot. something for me to remember when hacking other peoples examples. check the sizes fit ::)

Comment: Personally I like to use types as int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t and bool ... some of them are predefined, some are not. But this way I always know exactly what ranges I can use. When a range could change in the future, I use a typedef and give if a specific name, like I said above (typedef uint16_t buffer_size). That saves a lot of type replacement when changed.

Comment: I seem to remember problems using `unsigned` as types for loop indexes. Someone please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes, for example, if you count down, you cannot check for >= 0, because an unsigned value always is >= 0, but for counting up (until value 254 max) an unsigned byte can be used.

Comment: Ahh. Yes. I made this mistake before. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044067/3198973

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes ... sadly most compiler do not give a warning.